# How to use ContinueWith with this example

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, continuewith

I have following async method that is supposed to get all strings I need based on a list passed into the method:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetStrings(List selections)
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    TaskCompletionSource<List<string>> someStrings = new TaskCompletionSource<List<string>>();

    // Register/deregister event that is fired on each selection.
    // Once this event is received, I get its arguments from which I 
    // get string and add it to my list of strings.
    // Once the list count matches number of selections passed into the method,
    // TaskCompletionSource result is set.
    EventHandler<IDataNotification> onCallThatFiresCompleted = null;
    onCallThatFiresCompleted = (sender, e) =>
    {
        var myString = e.getString();
        myList.Add(myString);
        if (myList.Count == selections.Count)
        {
            MyObserver.DataNotification -= onCallThatFiresCompleted;
            someStrings.TrySetResult(myList);
        }
    };
    MyObserver.DataNotification += onCallThatFiresCompleted; 


    foreach (var sel in selections)
    {
        // This call fires onCallThatFiresCompleted event that when received 
        // will conteain string I need in its arguments.
        CallThatFires_MyEvent();
    }

    return await someStrings.Task; //await for the task
}
```

How would a caller of this method use Task.ContinueWith() to process returned List once the task is completed?  I want to do something like this:

```
foreach(var s in returnedStringList)
{
  // do something with the string s
}
```

Comment: Why use `Task.ContinueWith()` when the caller could just do  `var returnedStringList = await GetStrings(someList)`? Also, what problem are you having with doing `ContinueWith(` show the code of your attempt at doing it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are correct.  I could use await.  But I am trying to understand how to use ContinueWith and from what I read, it allows user to continue with returned data as soon as it is available.  But I cant figure out how to write the ContinueWith that would work in this case (or any other as I never used it before).  I also like the ability to control cancellations and faults that ContinueWith offers.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Not if the caller is `Main`  ;)

Comment: @KennethK. or if I don't want GetStrings() method to be an async method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to use ContinueWith with this example

You don't. You use `await`:

```
var returnedStringList = await GetStrings(..);
foreach(var s in returnedStringList)
{
  // do something with the string s
}
```

As I describe on my blog, [`await` is superior in every way to `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) for asynchronous code.